# Restore a whole docker-compose project from backup

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, backup, restore

Assuming the project was backed up with the following script:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pirate/265e19a8a768a48cf12834ec87fb0eed/raw/64145b8275a081e0c3082365bb1a5835c8b01b3c/docker-compose-backup.sh

and I have compressed tar archive with full backup, is there any "one-liner" way to successfully restore and run the project on clean machine?

Comment: dont provide external links which will change later. try to put the relevant code in question itself

Answer (score 2):

The standard “oops I lost all of my containers” Docker restore script should be roughly

```sh
# Get a copy of the repository with docker-compose.yml
git clone git@github.com:...

# Unpack a backup specifically of the bind-mounted
# data directories
tar xzf data-backup.tar.gz

# Recreate all of the containers from scratch
docker-compose up -d --build
```

This requires making sure all of the data in your application is stored somewhere outside individual Docker containers.  In a Docker Compose setup, that means using `volumes:` directives to store the data somewhere else.  A typical practice is to store as much data as you can in databases, and have no persistent data at all in non-database containers.  If you’re worried about losing the entire `/var/lib/docker` tree then prefer bind mounts to named volumes, and use whatever normal backup solution you normally use to back up the corresponding host directories.

The script you show tries to preserve a number of things that just don’t need to be backed up:

- If you’re preserving the database container’s data directory in a bind-mounted host directory, you don’t need to separately take a database-level backup (though it doesn’t hurt)
- `docker inspect` is an extremely low-level diagnostic tool and it’s usually not useful to run it; there’s nothing you can restore from it
- You don’t need to `docker save` the images because they’re in an external Docker registry (Docker Hub, AWS ECR, ...), and regardless you’ve checked their Dockerfiles into source control and can rebuild them
- You don’t need to `docker export` individual containers because they don’t keep mutable data, and you need to destroy them extremely routinely anyways

The one thing it does is to take advantage of reasonably-known Docker internal details to back up the content of named volumes.  Manually accessing files in `/var/lib/docker` isn’t usually a best practice and the actual format of the files there isn’t guaranteed.  The Docker documentation [discusses backing up and restoring named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) in a more portable way (but this is a place I find bind mounts to be much more convenient).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your concerns, however it does not correspond to my question. It's not about best practices. The backup is already done, in the format explicitly stated in the script (which is <backup_time>.tar.gz). I'm looking for a one-liner that will extract the contents of archive, build images locally and run it  (without repo cloning or connecting with external Docker registries).